# ssrs parameter expression condition

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, placeholder, ssrs-tablix

In SSRS (2014) I have created the Placeholder.

The value of Placeholder is picks from SQL 2014 DB StoredProcedure.

In the Placeholder properties, I have below expression,

```
=Parameters!BRN.Value
```

When I run the report,

Step 1: Report asks BRN value (which is integer). When I enter value
   as **"1"**

Step 2: Report displays **1**

If I pass BRN value as **2**
   it displays **2**

But I want below results,

Step 1: When Report asks BRN value (which is integer). If I enter value
   as **"1"** then it should display as "Winter"

or If I enter value
   as **"2"** then it should display as "Summer"

or If I enter value
   as **"3"** then it should display as "Spring"

or If I enter value
   as **"4"** then it should display as "Sunny"

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

=Switch(Parameters!BRN.Value = 1, "Winter", Parameters!BRN.Value = 2, "Summer", Parameters!BRN.Value = 3, "Spring", Parameters!BRN.Value = 4, "Sunny")